# Windows Product Key in Boot Menu

Tags: product-key

My Windows is corrupt now. There's some issue with the BCD.

What I wanted to know was is there anyway, I can get to know the Product Serial Key through the Boot Menu ?

As I guess, I'll be installing Windows 10 again.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: your title and the way you asked your question, is quite amusing.. I guess a more sensible question which is along the lines of what you mean would be if it's possible to get the product key from WinPE  or from plugging your drive in externally.. i.e. getting your product key from a windows that you aren't currently running.  This Britec video on making a Win 7 PE CD will help.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0eslpRmznE   You can run software from Win7 PE.. Then the question is which software

Comment: see my comment above, and by the way, a boot menu will never show a product key!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "through the boot menu"?  There are a number of previous answered questions about extracting the key in various ways, with or without booting Windows (but it isn't in the boot menu).  If it is an upgrade, you may not even need the key.  Also, if your Win 10 is an upgrade rather than a retail copy, you might want to explore the need to clean up the corruption before trying to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded from Windows 7 or 8, you don't need a product key.

1. Boot to the installation media.
2. Follow prompts until it asks for product key. **SKIP** product key request
3. Continue installation as you normally would
4. Windows 10 should activate automatically when you connect to the Internet